# Error while deploying through cargo: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: No more authentication mechanisms to try

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, cargo

I've been trying to deploy to a local JBoss 7 AS installation via the cargo maven plugin with no success. I've even tried enabling security for the JBoss's management interface to no avail.

Here is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
 <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.2</version>
 <configuration>
  <container>
   <containerId>jboss7x</containerId>
   <type>remote</type>
  </container>
  <configuration>
   <type>runtime</type>
   <properties>
    <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
    <cargo.jboss.management.port>9999</cargo.jboss.management.port>                              
   </properties>
  </configuration>                            
 </configuration>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
</plugin>
```

And the error I get:

```
Oct 31, 2011 10:32:08 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
Oct 31, 2011 10:32:08 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta2
Oct 31, 2011 10:32:08 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta2
Oct 31, 2011 10:32:08 AM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection handleException
ERROR: JBREM00200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: No more authentication mechanisms to try
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change port to 9990, but I'm not exactly sure that it will help!

Comment: I've tried all the ports but it looks like a bug in jBoss 7. Maybe this one: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11695

Comment: Maybe [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-7923) is related. I'll test if it works with the _jboss-as-maven-plugin_ instead of _cargo_ to see if I get it working that way, at least.

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem!
you can solve this by setting in your cargo /maven config the port to 8080 (should be the default if you are not setting the port)

Comment: What property from the plugin configuration are you referring to? "cargo.jboss.management.port"?